Find the newest element
Given a finite sequence, each of its elements has a first occurrence.  Your task is to output the symbol whose first occurrence is last in the sequence.  If the elements represent posts and reposts of memes over time, we want to see the newest meme!
Example
Input: A-BANAL-BANANA-LAB

A first occurs at position 0 (it occurs at positions 0,3,5,9,11,13,16)
- first occurs at position 1
B first occurs at position 2
N first occurs at position 4
L first occurs at position 6

max(0,1,2,4,6) = 6, so
Output: L
Input/output format
You can assume that the input sequence is nonempty, and is either a string of printable non-whitespace ASCII characters or a list of nonnegative integers in any reasonable form (your choice). You will output one element of the input sequence.
And of course
This is code-golf, so the shortest solution in each language wins.

I downvoted because the trivial solution to this is almost the same task as removing duplicates from a list, which is already a task on this site. (Not to say that's the only way, but it's the trivial and usually shortest way.)

Python, 26 bytes
lambda s:max(s,key=s.find)

Try it online!
Takes a string as input. s.find(c) outputs the first index in s where the character c appears, so using s.find as a key for max returns the character whose first occurrence in s comes latest.

JavaScript (ES6), 24 bytes
Note that it works because Set is guaranteed to maintain the insertion order of its elements.
s=>[...new Set(s)].pop()

Try it online!
Commented
s =>         // s = input string
[...         // turn into an array ...
  new Set(s) //   ... the set generated from s
             //       e.g. "BANANA" -> Set {'B','A','N'}
]            //
.pop()       // return the last element


APL (Dyalog Vision), 2 bytes
⊇∪

⊇ last ∪ unique

Google Sheets, 36 bytes
=chooserows(unique(tocol(A:A,1)),-1)

64 bytes:
=+let(β,A:A,γ,sort(row(β)),sort(β,1=countifs(β,β,γ,"<="&γ),,γ,))

...or:
=chooserows(filter(A:A,1=map(A:A,lambda(β,countif(A1:β,β)))),-1)

Put the array in column A1:A and the formula in cell B1.


For 35 you could be explicit about your range of elements using =INDEX(A:A,MAX(XMATCH(A1:A17,A:A))), and if we assume there is not going to be a pretty much endless string, then for 27 =CHOOSEROWS(UNIQUE(A:A),-2)

@JvdV yes... but I don't want to hardcode the range, nor assume that the data never fills the whole sheet down to the last row.

Yeah it feels better your way for sure.

C (tcc), 57 bytes
k;f(char*s){for(int v[128]={};*s;s++)k=v[*s]++?k:*s;k=k;}

Try it online!

Uiua SBCS, 3 bytes
⊢⇌◴

Try it!
⊢⇌◴­⁡​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁣⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌⁢​‎‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁡⁪‏⁠‎⁪⁡⁪⁠⁪⁢⁪‏‏​⁡⁠⁡‌­
  ◴  # ‎⁡deduplicate
⊢⇌   # ‎⁢last


Vyxal, 2 bytes
Ut

Try it Online!
 t # last
U  # unique element


Answered when the question was on 1 view :D

JavaScript (Node.js),  58  45  38 bytes
s=>[...s].map(a=e=>a[e]?0:a[e]=b=e)&&b

Try it online!

You can use the callback function as your object (38 bytes).

Perl 5 -MList::Util=uniq -pF, 15 bytes
$_=(uniq@F)[-1]

Try it online!

PowerShell, 27 bytes
($args|% *ay|select -u)[-1]

Try it online!
Ungolfed:
($args | ForEach-Object -Member ToCharArray | Select-Object -Unique)[-1]

Converts the input string to a char array by calling the string's member "ToCharArray", then selecting only unique characters, and picking the last char.

Excel ms365, 22 bytes
=@TAKE(UNIQUE(A:A),-2)



K (ngn/k), 4 bytes
The last *| unique ? element.
*|?:

Try it online!

Perl 5 + -0513pF, 22 bytes
-3 bytes thanks to @Xcali!
$\=chop;/${\}/&&redo}{
Try it online!

Slightly shorter, and doesn't use an additional module like my posted answer: Try it online!

Oh amazing work, thank you! Your solution is super clever too, nice - +1!

Brachylog, 2 bytes
dt

Try it online!
Nekomata, 2 bytes
ul

Attempt This Online!
More boring banal nub-tail solutions.

R 4.4.0, 21 bytes
\(x)tail(unique(x),1)

Attempt This Online!
Takes as input a vector of utf-8 code points. Really not fancy, basically just a port of Arnauld's JS answer (and several others as well).
Although R's base::unique() is not documented to guarantee insertion order, the implementation will do so. It loops through every value of a vector in order and checks if it has been seen before, appending to a new vector any which have not been. While I suppose it's possible this implementation will not remain forever, it will work in R 4.4.0. Also, the git blame indicates this has been part of the R source for 26 years - I don't imagine it would be changed lightly in future versions.

This is 22 bytes and guaranteed to work

@Giuseppe I think this is also guaranteed to work isn't it? At least in this and previous versions of R and until they change they R source. Though your approach is really nice.

Yeah, I think yours will work, but I offer the 22 bytes as an alternative you could include in your answer as well; I can post it as my own as well if you don't want to add it here.

@Giuseppe it's really nice but I can't take credit for it - it's a pretty different approach to mine I think (and more elegant as a solution) so feel free to post it as your own.

Setanta, 65 bytes
gniomh(s){le i idir(fad@s-1,-1)ma i<=aimsigh@s(s[i]) toradh s[i]}

try-setanta.ie link

Charcoal, 8 bytes
§θ⌈Ｅθ⌕θι

Try it online! Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation: Turned out to be a port of @xnor's answer.
    θ      Input string
   Ｅ       Map over characters
     ⌕     Index of
       ι   Current character
      θ    In input string
  ⌈        Take the maximum
§          Index into
 θ         Input string
           Implicitly print


Retina 0.8.2, 8 bytes
D`.
!`.$

Try it online! Takes input as a string. Explanation:
D`.

Keep only the first of each duplicated character.
!`.$

Keep the last remaining character.

MATL, 3 bytes
uJ)

Try it at matl.io
Explanation
     % Implicitly fetch input
u    % Find unique elements 
J)   % Get the last element
     % Print implicitly 


Haskell + hgl, 5 bytes
gj<nb

Attempt This Online!
Explanation
Nub and get the last element.
Parser, 16 bytes
gk$(h'>~nxy)<*h'

Attempt This Online!
Since this challenge is pretty trivial to do using the normal library, I thought I'd try a parser only version.
Explanation
We create a parser which matches all characters that are not preceded by a copy of themselves.

h': Get some prefix.
nxy: Parse a character not present in the prefix.
h': Parse some number of characters.
gk: Get the highest priority parse.

The priority here is determined by h' with the longest parse having the highest priority.
Reflection
The normal version of this can't reasonably be improved. Improvements can be made based on the parser version, but it will never be on par with the other version for this task.

gk gets the first complete parse. There should be a parser consumer which just gets the first parse. This would make the <*h' unnecessary and save a bunch of bytes here.
(h'*>) and (<*h') could probably use shortcuts. I use the former here. This would be superseded here by the above improvement, but would probably be useful in the long term.
I use (h'>~) here and here and the very similar (h_>~) here and here (the latter is now superseded by (h_<~)). There is some sort of common pattern here that seems likely to continue to pop up. I should have shortcuts for a bunch of these variants.

There are also some things I noticed which wouldn't save bytes here but should be done.

nχ and nxy could use versions precomposed with my and so.


R, 22 bytes
\(x)x[max(match(x,x))]

Attempt This Online!
A 1 byte longer solution than SamR's, but not implementation-dependent.

Python 3, 36 bytes
f=lambda x:list({a:0for a in x})[-1]

Try it online!

No need for f= here since it's not recursive. Save three using list splatting (list(...) -> [*...]), and another forming the dictionary from the sequence of elements paired with themselves ({a:0for a in x} -> {a:a for a in x} -> dict(zip(x,x))) - TIO

Desmos, 26 bytes
f(L)=U[U.count]
U=L.unique

Try It On Desmos!
Try It On Desmos! - Prettified

Java 21, 35 bytes
s->new LinkedHashSet<>().getLast()
A Function<List<T>, T> for some T. Requires Java 21 which does not seem to be available yet on Try It Online or Attempt This Online.

Japt v2.0a0 -h, 1 byte
â

Try it

Arturo, 15 bytes
$=>[last∪<=&]


Explanation
$=>[]  ; a function where input is assigned to &
last   ; last element of...
∪      ; union between...
<=&    ; input and itself              

This is two bytes shorter than last unique&, but requires the latest version for ∪, hence it won't work online yet.

K (ngn/k), 14 bytes
{x@|/x?!1+|/x}

Try it online!
Explanation
{x@|/x?!1+|/x}
{            } function
       !1+     enumerate from 0 to
          |/x  the max element of the list
     x?        find every element index
   |/          pick the newest element index
 x@            index


6?

J, 5 bytes
_1{~.

Nothing new.
Attempt This Online!
_1{~.
   ~.   NB. nub removes duplicates
_1{     NB. take the last item


Vyxal 3, 2 bytes
ut

try

t last of
u unique elements
of the input


Stack control, 3 characters:
∪⟄⟸

Explanation:
∪ - union (removes all duplicates)
⟄ - pop last element from array
⟸ - hard shift (removes original array)


AWK, 39 35 bytes
awk -F '' '{for(;i++<NF;)s[$i]++?z:l=$i;$0=l}1'

Explanation:

-F '' makes each character into its own field.

for(;i++<NF;): Iterate down the fields.

s[$1]++?z:: If the current field has been seen before, do nothing.

l=$i Otherwise, set l to the current field.



$0=l: Set $0 to the current value of l.

1: Print $0, i.e., print l.


Thanks to @Marius_Couet for shaving off several bytes.

AWK -F'', 35 bytes

By the way, how are we supposed to count bytes in AWK, if we have to specify the field separator with -F? Is that part of the program? What about the single-quotes around the program?

Oh, I see the convention is to say awk -F '' is a different language from awk. Makes sense to me!

Jelly, 2 bytes
QṪ

A monadic Link that accepts a list and yields the newest element.
Try it online!
How?
QṪ - Link: list, A
Q  - deduplicate {A}
 Ṫ - tail {that}


F# (.NET Core), 33 bytes
let f s=s|>Seq.distinct|>Seq.last

Try it online!
Shame the lambda solution is the same length, would have been an easy golf.

Ruby, 15 bytes
This version works with a list (conform to the rules):
->a{a.uniq[-1]}

Attempt This Online!
Ruby, 25 bytes
And this 25-bytes anonymous function takes a string as its input, splits in characters and outputs the last unique element:
->a{a.split('').uniq[-1]}

Attempt This Online!

->a{(a&a)[-1]} or ->a{*,x=a&a;x}

@radarek thank you! Your suggestions are interesting, publish them yourself!

Kotlin 2.0.0, 26 19 Bytes
{LinkedHashSet(it).last()}

A trivial port of David Conrad's Java solution. Expects a List<Char> and outputs a Char
{it.toSet().last()}

Saves 7 Bytes by using a Set instead of a LinkedHashSet. Sequence.toSet() preserves the original iteration order according to the docs
Try it Online

05AB1E, 2 bytes
Ùθ

Try it online.
Explanation:
Ù   # Uniquify the characters of the (implicit) input-string
 θ  # Pop and keep the last unique character
    # (which is output implicitly as result)


ARBLE, 19 bytes
index(-unique(l),1)

Try it online!
Per the challenge spec, takes a list of non-negative integers.
For 28 bytes, can take a string instead
index(-unique(split(s,1)),1)

Try it online!

JavaScript (Node.js), 33 bytes
s=>s.match(/(.)(?<!\1.+)/g).pop()

Try it online!

Pyth, 3 bytes
e{z

Try it online!
e      take last element (implicit print)
 {z    deduplicate z (=input)

